How to make new Map.groupBy work in TypeScript/Angular project?
I want to use the new Map.groupBy function in an NX/Angular/TypeScript project, but this is not working.
I had IDE errors saying that the function is unrecognized.
I've fixed that updating tsconfig.base.json file to use ESNext:
"lib": ["ESNext", "dom"],

Now my unit tests are not working at runtime due to a similar error:
Map.groupBy is not a function
TypeError: Map.groupBy is not a function

What are the requirements to make it work?

Are your tests failing at runtime? Do you actually have groupBy in your test environment (e.g. Node >=21)?

@jonrsharpe yes at runtime! How do you know which node version to use? I'm using ^v18, I gonna try with a newer version

You read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/groupBy#browser_compatibility, https://node.green. v18 definitely won't work, whatever you tell TypeScript.

@jonrsharpe thank you, that was the issue. I'd never paid attention that there was compatibility information with something else than browsers

See https://karma-runner.github.io/6.4/intro/how-it-works.html. Basically Karma runs code on server side (NodeJS) and client side (Browser). You need to make sure that your NodeJS runtime and your browser have support for the language features you are using.

yes, I'm using jest, but i guess that it's similar except for the browser part

This functionnality only works with node version >= 21.0.0 and I was using a lower version
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/groupBy#browser_compatibility
